# How to render two components while testing using react-testing library?

Tags: react-testing-library

i want to render two components using react testing library.

i have two components namely firstComponent and secondComponent

within my tests i render one compoennt like below

```
test('check test', async() => {
    const { getByTestId } = utils.render(
        <firstComp />,
        [
            utils.gqlMock(queryname, query-type),
        ]
    );
    //some logic here to do with getBytestid
)};
```

Now the question is how can i render component secondComponent with mock within utils.render method

i tried something like

```
test('check test', async() => {
    const { getByTestId } = utils.render(
        <secondComp/>,
        [  utils.gqlMock(queryname3, query-type3),
        ]
        <firstComp />,
        [
            utils.gqlMock(queryname, query-type),
        ]
    );
    //some logic here to do with getBytestid
)};
```

But this throws some errors. doesnt seem to be the right way. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never did this but I would try something like this :

```js
    const { getByTestId } = utils.render(
        <>
           <SecondComponent />
           <FirstComponent />
        </>,
        [...]
    );
```

Comment: I am new in testing, Is this good idea to call two components in one test file

Comment: It depends on your goal. If you want to do component unit testing you should render only one component in isolation. If you want to ensure that a group of components work together (like a parent component and some children receiving props from the parent), then you could switch to an integration test approach : render the parent, do not mock children, check that all goes well. I use to do this : always write unit tests for each component, event the simplest, then take a step back, and write some tests involving groups of components. See https://kentcdodds.com/blog/write-tests for inspiration